# Only one bootstrap modal opening--the others fade but modal does not appear

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

It seems that the only one modal on a given page will pop-up. The first modal that is defined seems to be the only one that opens. If i change of the order of the modal definitions, then the new "first" modal works but the others won't. Any clues as to why this is the case?

THE MODALS:

```
    <div class="flextable table-actions">
  <div class="flextable-item" style="padding-right:5px;">
    <div class="btn-toolbar-item input-with-icon">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-xs btn-primary-outline" data-target="#addBudgetOriginal" data-toggle="modal">Original Budget</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="flextable-item"  style="padding-right:5px;">
    <div class="btn-toolbar-item input-with-icon">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-xs btn-primary-outline" data-target="#myModal" data-toggle="modal">Approved Budget Change</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="flextable-item"  style="padding-right:5px;">
    <div class="btn-toolbar-item input-with-icon">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-xs btn-primary-outline" data-target="#addBudget" data-toggle="modal">Budget Reallocation</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="flextable-item flextable-primary">
    <div class="btn-toolbar-item input-with-icon">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-xs btn-primary-outline" data-target="#addBudget" data-toggle="modal">Pending Budget Reduction</button>
    </div>
  </div>
```

DEFINING THE MODALS AT THE BOTTOM OF MY HTML PAGE:

```
<!-- Modal for Add Budget Transaction -->
{% include 'modals/add_budget_modal - addBudgetOriginal.html' %}
{% include 'modals/add_budget_modal - addBudge.html' %}

<!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open Modal</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">

    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

The two includes blocks have modals with the following definitions:

```
<div id="addBudgetOriginal" class="modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
```

AND

```
<div id="addBudget" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
```

In this example, only the modal with the "#addBudgetOriginal" tag would pop-up and open because this modal is defined first. The other modals do not open. Any clues as to why? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to do something similar as shown in modal below.
And if answer is yes then check out [this link](https://nakupanda.github.io/bootstrap3-dialog/). It will demonstrate you how can you create your modal easily and that is also without having to write any conventional code.

```js
function simpleSHow(title)
   {
    var msg=$('#simple-div');
    
    BootstrapDialog.show({
     title : title,
     message: $('#simple-div'),
     onhide : function(){
      $('#hidden-div').append(msg);
     }
    });
   }
   
   function complexSHow(title)
   {
    var msg=$('#complex-div');
    
    BootstrapDialog.show({
     title : title,
     message: $('#complex-div'),
     onhide : function(){
      $('#hidden-div').append(msg);
     }
    });
   }
   
   function showDiv1(div_id)
   {
    var msg=$('#lavel-2_div-1');
    BootstrapDialog.show({
     title : 'Level 2 Title',
     message: $('#lavel-2_div-1'),
     onhide : function(){
      $('#hidden-div').append(msg);
     }
    });
   }
   
   function showDiv2(div_id)
   {
    var msg=$('#lavel-2_div-2');
    BootstrapDialog.show({
     title : 'Level 2 Title',
     message: $('#lavel-2_div-2'),
     onhide : function(){
      $('#hidden-div').append(msg);
     }
    });
   }
   
   function showDiv3(div_id)
   {
    var msg=$('#lavel-2_div-3');
    BootstrapDialog.show({
     title : 'Level 2 Title',
     message: $('#lavel-2_div-3'),
     onhide : function(){
      $('#hidden-div').append(msg);
     }
    });
   }
   
   function showDiv4(div_id)
   {
    var msg=$('#lavel-2_div-4');
    BootstrapDialog.show({
     title : 'Level 2 Title',
     message: $('#lavel-2_div-4'),
     onhide : function(){
      $('#hidden-div').append(msg);
     }
    });
   }
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap3-dialog/1.35.3/css/bootstrap-dialog.min.css" rel="stylesheet">


<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap3-dialog/1.35.3/js/bootstrap-dialog.min.js"></script>



<!--  This is a container Div which contains all the div to show when bootstrap dialog opens -->
<div style="display : none" id="hidden-div">
  <div id="simple-div">
    <h1>This is H1 Heading</h1>
    This is most simple coding
    <br>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="showDiv1()">Lavel-2 div-1</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="showDiv2()">Lavel-2 div-2</button>
  </div>

  <div id="lavel-2_div-1">
    <h3>This is Level 2 Header</h3>
    <span style="color : blue;">This is Level 2 Message 1</span>
  </div>

  <div id="lavel-2_div-2">
    <h3>This is Level 2 Header</h3>
    <span style="color : greenyellow;">This is Level 2 Message 2</span>
  </div>

  <div id="lavel-2_div-3">
    <h3>This is Level 2 Header</h3>
    <span style="color : pink;">This is Level 2 Message 3</span>
  </div>
  <div id="lavel-2_div-4">
    <h3>This is Level 2 Header</h3>
    <span style="color : green;">This is Level 2 Message 4</span>
  </div>

  <div class="container-fluid" id="complex-div">

    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="showDiv3()">Lavel-2 div-3</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="showDiv4()">Lavel-2 div-4</button>
    <h2>Panels with Contextual Classes</h2>
    <div class="panel-group">
      <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">Panel with panel-default class</div>
        <div class="panel-body">Panel Content</div>
      </div>

      <div class="panel panel-primary">
        <div class="panel-heading">Panel with panel-primary class</div>
        <div class="panel-body">Panel Content</div>
      </div>

      <div class="panel panel-success">
        <div class="panel-heading">Panel with panel-success class</div>
        <div class="panel-body">Panel Content</div>
      </div>

      <div class="panel panel-info">
        <div class="panel-heading">Panel with panel-info class</div>
        <div class="panel-body">Panel Content</div>
      </div>

      <div class="panel panel-warning">
        <div class="panel-heading">Panel with panel-warning class</div>
        <div class="panel-body">Panel Content</div>
      </div>

      <div class="panel panel-danger">
        <div class="panel-heading">Panel with panel-danger class</div>
        <div class="panel-body">Panel Content</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>

&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="simpleSHow('Hello 1234')">Simple Div Show</button>
&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="complexSHow('Complex 1234')">Complex Div Show</button>
```